KeyError at /verify/ 'order_id'
I have a problem on my store site, when I want to confirm my order, when I click on confirmation on the payment page, it gives this error instead.
the error
Internal Server Error: /verify/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 143, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\cart\views.py", line 124, in get
    order_id = request.session['order_id']
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\QK\Desktop\MAworkshop\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'order_id'
[26/Jul/2024 09:38:14] "GET /verify/?Authority=000000000000000000000000000001476833&Status=OK HTTP/1.1" 500 83027
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[26/Jul/2024 09:38:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5053


I asked some people what should I do to solve my problem and they told me that I didn't set the order_id in the session.
view.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from account.models import Address
from .models import Order, OrderItem, DiscountCode
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from product.models import Product
from django.conf import settings
from django.views import View
from .cart_module import Cart
import requests
import json


class CartView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        cart = Cart(request)
        return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', {'cart': cart})


class AddCartView(View):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        cart = Cart(request)
        cart.add(product, quantity, request)
        return redirect('cart:cart')


class DeleteCartView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        cart = Cart(request)
        cart.delete(id)
        return redirect('cart:cart')


class OrderDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=pk)
        return render(request, 'cart/order.html', {'order': order})



class OrderCreationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        cart = Cart(request)
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, total_price=cart.total())
        request.session['order_id'] = order.id  # ذخیره شناسه سفارش در جلسه
        # ...
        return redirect('cart:order-detail', order.id)




class ApplyDiscountView(View):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        code = request.POST.get('discount_code')
        order_id = request.session.get('order_id')  # استفاده از .get() برای جلوگیری از KeyError
        if order_id is None:
            # انجام اقدامات لازم در صورت عدم وجود 'order_id' در جلسه
            return HttpResponse("Order ID not found in session.", status=400)

        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
        discount_code = get_object_or_404(DiscountCode, name=code)
        # ...



#? sandbox merchant
if settings.SANDBOX:
    sandbox = 'sandbox'
else:
    sandbox = 'www'

ZP_API_REQUEST = f"https://{sandbox}.zarinpal.com/pg/rest/WebGate/PaymentRequest.json"
ZP_API_VERIFY = f"https://{sandbox}.zarinpal.com/pg/rest/WebGate/PaymentVerification.json"
ZP_API_STARTPAY = f"https://{sandbox}.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/"

amount = 1000  # Rial / Required
description = "ساعاتی بعد از خرید با شما برای انتخاب ظاهر محصول تماس گرفته میشود"  # Required
phone = 'YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER'  # Optional
# Important: need to edit for realy server.
CallbackURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/'
        

class SendRequestView(View):
    def post(self, request, pk):

        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=pk, user=request.user)
        address = get_object_or_404(Address, id=request.POST.get('address'))
        order.address = f"{address.address} - {address.phone}"
        order.save()
        request.session['order_id'] = str(order.id)

        data = {
            "MerchantID": settings.MERCHANT,
            "Amount": order.total_price,
            "Description": description,
            "Phone": request.user.phone,
            "CallbackURL": CallbackURL,
        }
        data = json.dumps(data)
        # set content length by data
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': str(len(data))}
        try:
            response = requests.post(ZP_API_REQUEST, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=10)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                response = response.json()
                if response['Status'] == 100:
                    return redirect(ZP_API_STARTPAY + str(response['Authority']))
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'status': False, 'code': str(response['Status'])})
            return JsonResponse(response)

        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            return JsonResponse({'status': False, 'code': 'timeout'})
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            return JsonResponse({'status': False, 'code': 'connection error'})

class VerifyView(View):
    def get(self, request):

        order_id = request.session['order_id']
        if order_id is None:

            return HttpResponse("Order ID not found in session.", status=400)

        order = Order.objects.get(id=str(order_id))
        data = {
            "MerchantID": settings.MERCHANT,
            "Amount": order.total_price,
            "Authority": request.get("Authority"),
        }
        data = json.dumps(data)
        # set content length by data
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': str(len(data))}
        response = requests.post(ZP_API_VERIFY, data=data, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            response = response.json()
            if response['Status'] == 100:
                order.is_paid = True
                return {'status': True, 'RefID': response['RefID']}
            else:
                return {'status': False, 'code': str(response['Status'])}
        return response


I couldn't think of anything, I asked other people to try, but they couldn't help me either

I am not sure but it looks to me like you set the session for the user and then call an external API sandbox.zarinpal.com giving it a "callback" URL which I am guessing that API will call to verify stuff? The API won't really have the users session when they call you. This would probably be more clear if you linked to the API docs for the API you're using and added your URLs file over here. It looks to me like you're not understanding the flow that API is supposed to go through.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I think it's better to use "request.session.get('order_id')" instead of "request.session['order_id']" here. Try it. I hope your bug will be fixed.

This is half the answer: more generally, the code needs to be modified to correctly handle the case where order_id is not defined yet.
